Is there a better format than PNG to store R16uint depth data on Android?
Is there a better format than PNG to store R16uint depth data on Android
I find I get precision artifacts when using ASTC.

I get the sense from your past four questions that there's an effect you want to achieve, but the way you're trying to achieve it isn't quite working the way you want. Unfortunately, you've never told us what that overarching goal is, just asked about individual symptoms. This leads us to an XY problem, where an efficient way to achieve your end goal may exist, but none of our experts here will know to suggest it because they can't see what you're trying to do. I'd recommend backing up and asking "how to achieve this effect", including examples.

Better in what way? You've identified that you've run into a precision problem with ASTEC, but you haven't shared the problem you have with using PNG. Without knowing why PNG isn't good enough &/or explaining the context of your problem, readers can only guess at alternatives. What problem are you having with using PNG to store depth data?

depends on what you are aiming for. a raw blob of 16 bit values also works

Thanks for all:)
